# how to pass string as key in dictionary

Tags: python

i want to parse dictionary dynamically 
here i'm trying to get the name of key dynamically and storing that key in variable and call dictionary using those variable
so far i tried this

```
   var=users.to_dict()
    z=var.keys()
    y=z[0]

x=var[str(y)]['Scheme name']
```

when i pass str(y) it giving error

```
    y=x[0]
TypeError: 'dict_keys' object does not support indexing
```

is there any better ways to this. please let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cannot index 'dict_keys' but if you parse them to 'list'

```
var=users.to_dict()
z=list(var.keys())
y=z[0]
```

x=var[str(y)]['Scheme name']

it should work

Answer (score 0):

```
y=z[0]
```

is where your error is.

`var.keys()` doesn't return a list, it returns a `dict_keys`, which doesn't support indexing.  You can convert it to an list and then index:

```
y = list(x)[0]
```

However, `z = list(var)` will have the same effect (list of keys) and is a little more direct.

A `dict_keys` behaves this way because it's a [view object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects).  It's an iterable whose contents change if the underlying dictionary changes.  The result of casting it as a list (or casting the dictionary as a list) is that it's no longer connected to dictionary.